# \midrule length goes beyond width of table

Tags: tabularx, width

I would like to have the `midrule` of my table to the same length as the width of my table.  With the code that I currently have, this is the output that I get:

[image]

Can you please help me get the `midrule` to be the same size as my table's width?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[article, english]{book}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ctable}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
%\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}
\rowcolors{2}{blue!20}{white}
%\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llll}
\rowcolor{blue!50}
\textbf{Freq} & \textbf{Board} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}PTT\\   ACC\end{tabular}} & \textbf{MAP} \\
136.0125 & 508  & -62.1 & -61.5 \\
173.9875 & 508  & -61.2 & -61.1 \\
380.0125 & 508  & -59.8 & -59.9 \\
519.9875 & 508  & -59   & -58.8 \\
764.0625 & 508  & -56.8 & -56.6 \\
869.8875 & 508  & -55.8 & -55.7 \\
\midrule[2pt]
136.0125 & 3511 & -61.9 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-55.0 \\
173.9875 & 3511 & -61.7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-55.0 \\
380.0125 & 3511 & -59.7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-54.5 \\
519.9875 & 3511 & -58.7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-54.3 \\
764.0625 & 3511 & -56.5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-53.4 \\
869.8875 & 3511 & -55.5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-53.0
\end{tabularx}                                      
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: in `tabularx` at least one column should be `X` tyoe. otherwise use `tabular` table environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behaviour or [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) is to set a table of width given by the first argument - `\textwidth` in your case. Additionally, it requires the use of at least one `X`-column in order to stretch to that width. If none are supplied, there's really no need for a `tabularx`.

To this end, don't use `tabularx`, but `tabular` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \rowcolors{2}{blue!20}{white}%
  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{l} }
    \rowcolor{blue!50}
    \textbf{Freq} & \textbf{Board} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{ @{} l @{} }PTT \\ ACC\end{tabular}} & \textbf{MAP} \\
    136.0125 & 508  & -62.1 & -61.5 \\
    173.9875 & 508  & -61.2 & -61.1 \\
    380.0125 & 508  & -59.8 & -59.9 \\
    519.9875 & 508  & -59   & -58.8 \\
    764.0625 & 508  & -56.8 & -56.6 \\
    869.8875 & 508  & -55.8 & -55.7 \\
    \specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    136.0125 & 3511 & -61.9 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-55.0 \\
    173.9875 & 3511 & -61.7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-55.0 \\
    380.0125 & 3511 & -59.7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-54.5 \\
    519.9875 & 3511 & -58.7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-54.3 \\
    764.0625 & 3511 & -56.5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-53.4 \\
    869.8875 & 3511 & -55.5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-53.0
  \end{tabular}                                      
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\specialrule{<width>}{<above sep>}{<below sep>}` to avoid coloured gaps between rows that have colours.

Answer (score 6):

as i noted in my comment, table environment should has at least on ˛`X` type of column.  since your table is your table is relatively narrow, is better to use `tabular` environment and rather gives some attention to column desing. for them i suggest to use `S` column type provided by package `makecell`, for column headers use `\thead` from package `makecell`. instead `midrule` i would rather use `Xhline{<thiknes>}` also from `makecel`:

```
\documentclass[article, english]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{FE0000}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{12pt}
\rowcolors{2}{blue!20}{white}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.4]
                S[table-format=4.0]
                S[table-format=-2.1]
                S[table-format=-2.1]
                }
\rowcolor{blue!50}
{\thead{Frequency}}
            & {\thead{Board}}
                    & {\thead{PTT\\ ACC}}
                            & {\thead{MAP}}         \\
136.0125    & 508   & -62.1 & -61.5                 \\
173.9875    & 508   & -61.2 & -61.1                 \\
380.0125    & 508   & -59.8 & -59.9                 \\
519.9875    & 508   & -59   & -58.8                 \\
764.0625    & 508   & -56.8 & -56.6                 \\
869.8875    & 508   & -55.8 & -55.7                 \\
    \Xhline{2pt}
136.0125    & 3511  & -61.9 & \cellcolor{myred}-55.0 \\
173.9875    & 3511  & -61.7 & \cellcolor{myred}-55.0 \\
380.0125    & 3511  & -59.7 & \cellcolor{myred}-54.5 \\
519.9875    & 3511  & -58.7 & \cellcolor{myred}-54.3 \\
764.0625    & 3511  & -56.5 & \cellcolor{myred}-53.4 \\
869.8875    & 3511  & -55.5 & \cellcolor{myred}-53.0
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]